# Back failed for Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, smo

http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/202843/take-backup-of-sql-server-database-using-c

Error :
Back failed for Server

I am using smo code from this thread , but it cant backup...

My Code :

```
    Server s = new Server(".\\SQLEXPRESS");
    Backup bk = new Backup();
    bk.Devices.AddDevice(backupText.Text, DeviceType.File);
    bk.Database = "System";
    bk.Action = BackupActionType.Database;
    bk.SqlBackup(s);
```

Comment: A more detailed error message would help.  Usual suspects here are lack of permissions or a bad value in backupText.Text.

Comment: I listed the error above... I commented my last 5 lines , problem lies in server connection

Comment: @Great I know you listed the error, but it's a useless message.  There is a more detailed error message somewhere - through the exception window in the VS debugger or somewhere.

Comment: Yes the database is on my p.c I am already connected with it in my app. Just backup through smo not working

Comment: A first chance exception of type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.FailedOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll (u Mean this)

Comment: Yes, post the exception details for that and any inner exceptions.

Comment: Inner exception is Failed to connect server ...

Comment: why a -2 ? cant i ask question

Comment: So which part of `Failed to connect server ...` don't you understand? It seems you don't have a SQL Server instance called `.\SQLEXPRESS` on that machine where your code runs - or it's not running.

Comment: "user id = ; password = ; server="+System.Environment.MachineName+"\\SQLEXPRESS; Trusted_Connection = yes; database = System; Connection timeout = 10; MultipleActiveResultSets=True , i am already connected with this string.

Comment: Problem Solved... Permission Problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was of permission.. For Connecting to sql server for taking backup backup permission is required. So Kindly Check permission section.